# Taking a screenshot of flash game/animation, server-side? (or client-side?)

Tags: javascript, flash, client-side, server-side, snapshot

I'm just wondering, is it possible for a server-side script to take screenshot of a flash animation (no matter the time in the animation, resolution etc) located on the server?

Also acceptable would be a solution that could make use of client-side scripting, like JavaScript, but which could then upload the screenshot to the server (actually, now that I'm thinking about it, this one makes more sense... but I'll just leave the title like that, so it sounds more interesting).

So does anyone have any idea?

For you to understand better, here is an example:

Say I'm starting a flash games website, or flash animations website. Now I already have 22,403 flash animations on my server (duh...)  and want my users to be able to take a sneak peak in the game before they play it, offering them a screenshot or image from inside the game before starting (just like most of the flash game websites do...).

And yeah, I don't really want to make all the 22k-something snapshots myself (load the game, press printscreen, paste in Microsoft Paint, cut the game, save and upload... I mean, seriously?

I hope you understood me a little.

If you have any ideas, please don't hesitate to shout it to me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use webkit and virtual X server. Here is a simple tool:

http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

> For example, while plugin support can be enabled, and the plugins
>   execute properly, their rendering cannot be captured on some
>   platforms. Use of with caution.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Another plugin? It's better to implement a built-in screenshot feature in the flash object. Nice avatar btw :)

Comment: No, its not a plugin. Its server side screenshot maker solution. I am saw a lot of screenshots examples which contains a flash banners :)

Comment: How are you supposed to take a screenshot of the clients screen at the server's side, without transmitting the data about the client's "game" state?

Comment: You cant control flash in this method. But you can get usefull tool, which save a lot of time: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce